# Item separator for context menu in Android

Tags: android

Is it possible to add a separator between menu items in Android's context menu? I don't see any directions for this in the documentation. Apparently menu items should be separated in some cases when they perform operations of a different kind.

NB. The question is about context menu, not options menu.

Comment: Context Menu Shows it content in the form of list with thin line as separator what kind of separator you want to add ?

Comment: Well, I mean a distinctive separator. In most of other programming environments there is a special separator "item", which displays a logical boundary between groups of items. You can take a look at Chrome setting menu for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I thought of only one workaround - a custom implementation of a context menu, such as [Icon Context Menu](http://code.google.com/p/iconcontextmenu/) for example. Such a code allows for extending menu item class to a specific menu separator class with custom view.

<sub>... But some time later I have found that ...</sub>

Another (much easier) solution could be adding a menu item with a row of '_' (underline) characters (surprisingly this is the only symbol in *standard* Android font which multiple instances can be shown smoothly side by side without gaps), and then aligning the item text in Java code using `SpannableString`.

**String resource**:

```
<string name="hr">______________________________</string>
```

Adjust the string length as appropriate.

**Menu layout**:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="none" android:enabled="false">
   <item android:id="@+id/menu_gap"
      android:title="@string/hr"
      android:enabled="false" />
</group>
```

**Java**:

```
private void alignCenter(MenuItem item)
{
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString(item.getTitle());
    s.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER), 0, s.length(), 0);
    item.setTitle(s);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not able to comment and maybe I'm a bit late but I hope this will help someone. For what I know: Android adds a separator between groups if you enable this via ContextMenu.setGroupDividerEnabled.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle(R.string.choose_action);
    menu.add(0, MENU_ITEM_CREATE, 0, R.string.create);
    menu.add(1, MENU_ITEM_CHECK, 0, R.string.check);
    menu.add(2, MENU_ITEM_EDIT, 0, R.string.edit);
    menu.add(2, MENU_ITEM_DELETE, 1, R.string.delete);

    // Enable group separator
    menu.setGroupDividerEnabled(true);
}
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu#setGroupDividerEnabled(boolean)

Comment: `ContextMenu.setGroupDividerEnabled` requires API version 28