# Popup menu divider for App compat theme

Tags: android, popupmenu

I used app compat theme style .

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
        <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/myCustomMenuTextApearance</item>
        <item name="android:listPopupWindowStyle">@style/PopupMenuStyle</item>

    </style>
    <style name="PopupMenuStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:divider">@drawable/devider</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">2dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/search_panel_color</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/activity_button_text_color</item>
        <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/activity_theam_color</item>


    </style>

    <style name="myCustomMenuTextApearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/activity_theam_color</item>
    </style>
```

I want to add a divider in my menu item.
I've tried so many things, but the divider is not applying...
Is there any way to show the divider?

Comment: Did you try `dropDownListViewStyle` ?

Comment: yes i tried. not working

Comment: It's working fine with me

Comment: Is there any thing missing in this style?

Comment: if multiple style.xml in your app for different api level then cross check with all.

Comment: there is only one style in app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have one solution.you can design popup as per your choice by programming.use below code to display popup menu.

```
private ListPopupWindow listPopupWindow;
listPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(getApplicationContext());
listPopupWindow.setWidth(400);
listPopupWindow.setDropDownGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
listPopupWindow.setAdapter(new listpopupadapter(a, type));
listPopupWindow.setAnchorView(v);
listPopupWindow.show();
```

Here listpopupadapter is class to design your list as it below.

```
public class listpopupadapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<String> a;
    String type;

    public listpopupadapter(ArrayList<String> a, String type) {
        this.a = a;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return a.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return getItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View root = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.raw_filter, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: working.. thanks!! this is custom style may be it s working for every style.

Answer (score 7):

I also have the same problem.  The solution is like this:

```
<style name="PopupMenuListView" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:divider">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">   
  <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/PopupMenuListView</item>
</style>
```

You can also refer to the following link:
[How to add dividers between specific menu items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33277124/how-to-add-dividers-between-specific-menu-items)

Answer (score 2):

From your theme style, I guessed you used `Toolbar`. Is your menu popup is showed from `Toolbar`? If so, you can customize as the following step.

Define the theme

```
<style name="AppToolbarPopupTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/AppDropDownListViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppDropDownListViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/line_divider</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
</style>
```

Then apply the theme to `Toolbar`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppToolbarPopupTheme">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you haven't found the answer to this question then this is how it worked for me using the style:

```
    <style name="PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/background_medium_gray</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/BackgroundGray</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
</style>

    Context context = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.PopupMenu);
    final PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, view);

    final MenuInflater menuInflater = popupMenu.getMenuInflater();
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you add dummy groups,try this way

```
<group>
    <!--add it like as a separator-->
    <item
        android:title=""
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:enabled="false" />
</group>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a Material theme removes dividers.May be this is the simple solution to this problem.

You can try this or any holo theme (i.e @android:style/Widget.ListPopupWindow) to get divider effect in popup

```
<!-- Change Overflow Menu ListView Divider Property -->
<style name="PopupMenuListView" parent="android:Widget.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:divider">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">2dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a driver app that needed a popup the ride was coming, at that time I used this one. So please try this one. Maybe it will help.

```
<activity
    android:name="driver_activity_name
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

Comment: your answer should be adapted to the question

Comment: and what is your driver activity name, i mean where i apply this ? I have activity with custom popup menu,

Comment: ✞ you already defined in manifest just add filter with this theme.May be its Works ✞