# Option menu with lines between options.like a divider between options that are displayed in menu

Tags: android, menu

In my application i have option menu which is placed in top as default.When we press that menu will open in that menu their is no lines between options.i want to display lines between then like a divider.

I try to change theme it work but i wont an other solution because if i change theme it will effect my application totally.

it is work in AppTheme not in AppTheme.AppCompat.

i want it is work with out change in themes.

If any one want code i will post it.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:showDividers">beginning</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@color/action_bar_divider</item>
</style>
```

Comment: i have posted some solution here try it.

Comment: i have updated my answer check it

Comment: i accept the answer thanks is it possible to reduce width of the menu line.

Comment: yes.try dividermargin you get.?

Comment: dividermargin is not working.

Comment: marginleft and margin right you not get?

Comment: i try those all not working if we take layout margin if effect total layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is many ways to achieve this.

**solution 1 ==> you can make group in menu xml like below**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<group android:id="@+id/grp1">
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_item_1"
    android:checked="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
    android:title="@string/navigation_item_1" /></group>

<group android:id="@+id/grp2">
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_item_2"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
    android:title="@string/navigation_item_2" /></group></menu>
```

**solution 2==> you can make custom action layout like below**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_cart"
    android:title="cart"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/custom_layout"
    android:icon="@drawable/shape_notification"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

**and actionLayout file like below**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<View
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/divider"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"          
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"/>
```

**solution 3 ==> you can make custom theme for particular activity**

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item></style>


 <style name="ActionBar"parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
<item name="android:background">@color/action_bar_background</item>
<item name="android:showDividers">beginning</item>
<item name="android:divider">@color/action_bar_divider</item></style>
```

**solution 4==> you can custom view for DropdownlistView**

```
<style name="PopupMenuListView" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
<item name="android:divider">#000000</item>
<item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">   


 <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/PopupMenuListView</item></style>
```

you can refer this link [add divider in menu item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33277124/how-to-add-dividers-between-specific-menu-items)

Comment: I try all solutions what you suggest but none of this work still i am getting problem.

Comment: First two solutions i already try not work if we change the theme it effect my project i want keep AppCompatTheme.

Comment: @BhargaviYamanuri just add in your app theme  <item name="android:showDividers">beginning</item>
<item name="android:divider">@color/action_bar_divider</item>

Comment: this is also not working.following is my theme check is there any problem.

Comment: i try to create groups with different id's then also not worked there is any other solution.from past two days i try to get it but it is not happen,i try every suggestion in google and stackoverflow.

Comment: That link work.It is amazing change your answer i will accept it.@Jiangbo Wang answer is worked perfectly with out effecting any theme.Thank u very much for helping me.