# Divider lines in overflow menu

Tags: android, android-menu, overflow-menu

Is it possible to put divider lines between groups of menu items in an overflow menu in Android?

Dividers are a standard feature of menus, and have been for at least 30 years. So it seems a bit weird if this isn't possible in a non-trivial way.

For example, the `Chrome` menu on OSx looks like this:

[image]

I'm talking about the lines between some of the menu items. Is there a way to get something similar in the overflow and/or context menus in Android without resorting to custom views and whatnots?

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625280/how-to-create-a-simple-divider-in-the-new-navigationview/30625471#30625471

Comment: refer this,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33277124/how-to-add-dividers-between-specific-menu-items