# I want to display separorator line between group of menu in menu toolbar. How to create it?

Tags: android, menu, action, android-toolbar

I want to create separorator line betwenn group of menu in toolbar.
Here is my code.

```
<group
        android:id="@+id/group1"
        >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/item_saveall"
            android:title="Save All"
            />
    </group>
    <group>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/item_share"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/item_about"
            android:title="About us" />
    </group>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add    android:checkableBehavior="single"

```
<group android:id="@+id/group1" android:checkableBehavior="single" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_saveall"
        android:title="Save All" />
</group>
<group  android:id="@+id/group2" android:checkableBehavior="single"  >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_share"
        android:title="Share" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_about"
        android:title="About us" />
</group>
```

Comment: I have set group id in both but still its now working.

Comment: add android:checkableBehavior="single" ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create you own adapter/ layout etc... for the menu.
Like described here:
[How to add dividers between specific menu items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33277124/how-to-add-dividers-between-specific-menu-items)