# Custom divider between item in menu android

Tags: android, menu

I try to make a menu as in the image below.

[image]

I did as the code below, but the divider 2 is the same as divider 1. How can i create a divider like as divider 2 in the picture(the divider 2 is bigger than divider 1). Thanks in advance!!

```
<group android:id="@+id/group1" android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/account_setting"
        android:icon="@drawable/perm_group_calendar"
        android:title="アカウント設定"
        />
</group>

<group android:id="@+id/group2" android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/notification_setting"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_home"
        android:title="通知設定"

        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/passcode_setting"
        android:icon="@drawable/sym_action_email"
        android:title="パスコード設定"
        />
</group>


<group android:id="@+id/group4" android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/management_sale_note"
        android:icon="@drawable/perm_group_calendar"
        android:title="管理営業士ノート" />
</group>

<group android:id="@+id/group5" android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/photo_list"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_home"
        android:title="写真一覧" />
</group>

<group android:id="@+id/group6" android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/medicine_notebook"
        android:icon="@drawable/sym_action_email"
        android:title="お薬手帳" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/medication_delivery_status"
        android:icon="@drawable/perm_group_calendar"
        android:title="お薬の配送状況" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/interview_sheet"
        android:icon="@drawable/perm_group_calendar"
        android:title="問診票" />
    </group>
<group android:id="@+id/group9" android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/payment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_home"
        android:title="お支払い" />
</group>
```

Comment: follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33277124/how-to-add-dividers-between-specific-menu-items)

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  @NileshRathod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating two separate lists and having one sit below the other using a constraint margin of your choosing.